If A is nonsingular matrix and we have $||B - A|| < ||A^{-1}||^{-1}$ (which ||.|| is a matrix norm related to vector norm) then proof B is nonsingular
I want to prove the following statement:
If $A$ is a nonsingular matrix, and we have $\lVert B - A\rVert < \lVert A^{-1}\rVert^{-1}$ (where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is a matrix norm related to the vector norm) then $B$ is nonsingular.
The definition for the matrix norm asked in the question is like below: 
I don't want a full answer for this question, but I don't know where to start. I can relate these norms to the singular values of the two matrices
A
and
B
−
A
, but I don't have any useful ideas. Could anyone help me?

could you give me more detail? this norms is talking about x which makes it supremum. what does  x do here?

Do you know that $|C-I|<1$ implies $C$ is invertible? If yes, apply this to $A^{-1}B$

I'll use @geetha290krm's idea that $\lVert C-I\rVert <1$ implies that $C$ is invertible. Here's a proof: Proof of "$\| I-A\|<1$ implies $A$ is invertible" using contraction mapping
Since $A$ is non-singular, $A^{-1}$ exists, thus
$$
\lVert A^{-1}B-I\rVert\leqslant \lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\lVert B-A\rVert<1.
$$
Therefore $A^{-1}B$ is invertible, hence $B$ must be invertible/non-singular (you can use the fact that $\det(A^{-1}B)=\det(A^{-1})\det B\neq 0$).

In addition, regarding the definition of matrix norms (induced from vector norms), here's how I like to think about it.
A norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert $ on a vector space $V$ (over $F$) is a map $V\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies the axioms:
$\forall u,v\in V,a\in F$,

$\lVert v\rVert=0\iff v=0$;

$\lVert av\rVert = |a|\lVert v\rVert$;

$\lVert u+v\rVert\leqslant \lVert u\rVert + \lVert v\rVert$.


Now we want to define a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ on the vector space $\mathcal L(V,W)$, where $V$ and $W$ are normed vector spaces (with corresponding norms $\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_W$), and $\mathcal L(V,W)$ denotes the set of all linear mappings from $V$ to $W$. We start by observing the fact that
$$
\lVert L\rVert=\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{\lVert Lv\rVert_W}{\lVert v\rVert_V}
=\sup_{\lVert v\rVert_V=1}\lVert Lv\rVert_W
$$
satisfies the three axioms of a norm. The supremum (or maximum) ensures some nice properties, such as
$$
\lVert Lv\rVert_W\leqslant \lVert L\rVert\cdot\lVert v\rVert_V
$$
which is called consistency. However, I want to emphasize that not all operator norms have this property; for a counterexample, let $M^{m\times n}$ be a matrix, and $m_{ij}$ be the entry from row $i$, column $j$. We define
$$
\lVert M^{m\times n} \rVert = \max_{i,j}|m_{ij}|
$$
Since $M$ is finite-dimensional the maximum is well-defined. It is easy to see that this norm is not consistent.
If you're familiar with functional analysis you may know that we can define a norm ("supremum norm") on the function space $C(a, b)$ of all continuous functions that are defined on a closed interval $[a, b]\subset \mathbb R$ as follows:
$$
\| y \|_{\infty} \equiv \max_{a \leq x \leq b} |y(x)| \quad \text{where} \quad y \in C(a, b),
$$
Since a linear operator is, in fact, a function, we would like to define it the same way, but vector spaces are not bounded (unlike the inteval $[a,b]$), making the maximum ill-defined. However, by exploiting the linear structure of a vector space, we can take the maximum over the bounded set $\{v\in V:\lVert v\rVert_V=1\}$ instead.
